# Ping request time out although web browser works on same computer

Tags: windows, windows-7, cmd, ping

I'm on the World Wide Web right now, as evidenced by posting on StackOverflow. However, if I try to `ping stackoverflow.com` from the command line, the ping times out. What do I need to do for ping to work?

```
> ping stackoverflow.com

Pinging stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.140] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 198.252.206.140:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

## Edit, try `tracert`

```
> tracert stackoverflow.com

Tracing route to stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.140] over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 ...
 Trace complete.
```

It's `Request timed out.` all the way to 30 hops.

## Edit, try `ping google.com`

Same result. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some hosts have a firewall that block the ICMP (http://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) packets like ping. You can use traceroute (cmd line tool or online webs like http://ping.eu/traceroute/) or tcptraceroute (http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcptraceroute).

Some routers also have a firewall that block ICMP. You can detect this by doing `ping google.com`. It that fails, then it's your local router that's problematic not the remote host.

hope it can help you

Comment: It might be firewall rules on his router as well. I have done this same exact thing to myself. :X

Comment: @PhilWalton I'm at a cafe, using its router. Is there a way to determine if it's the router at the cafe?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin you can use `ping google.com` if you still receive a loss packet it's because you (router, HW firewall, SW firewall...) are blocking the packet

Comment: @nada I'm using `ping stackoverflow.com`, so that's likely equivalent, eh?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin yes but i know google.com accept ICMP packets so if you can't ping google.com it's becaouse a firewall or so. Use `TCPtraceroute` if you can. You can specify the port 80 with this tool and almost all the cases the port 80 is open

Comment: So, given my tracert results and the replication of them with `google.com`, is it the router at the cafe?

Comment: Yes i think it's your router