# Can connect via Postman but not via python script

Tags: python, api, http, python-requests, postman

I am helping my client to solve a problem. He tries to call my API but is unsuccessful.

#### Situation:

- my API is accessible via postman and the browser (swagger).  It works.
- On the same computer via a python script I cannot access to the API

#### error:

> Caused by NewCOnnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001310A6F5C0>:
>   Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')

If I try a very simple script

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://google.com')
```

I get the same error.

I assume there some problem with firewall/proxy but why does Postman work?
In which direction can I direct my client to solve problem?

I also tried `ping` and it doesn't work either:

```sh
$ ping www.google.com

Ping request could not found host www.google.com. Pleas check the name and try again.
```

Comment: Are you using any multi-threading?, The code which you specified works perfect.

Comment: Yes code works perfect on my computer as well,... but on client machine it doesn't,... There I get an error as describe above,...

Comment: You could try to ping first on bash to check if it has access to the website, if not something on the client's end is blocked and you have to fix that first before running the code

Comment: ping doesn't work as well,...

Comment: Make sure you have access to the public internet on the client machine.

Comment: But in the question you mentioned in the same machine you were able to access API via postman?? how are you able to?

Comment: Increase the request timeout (seconds): requests.get('url', timeout=5)
I think it is because of multi threading.

Comment: @SundeepPidugu, yes this is so weird for me,... google works in browser and in postman all APIs works as well,... but ping curl and python can't reach outside world,..

Comment: @adamStrauss I also try this and it didn't work,... It shouldn't be multi threading because I only run this simple script,.. also ping is not multi threaded,...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826271/ping-request-time-out-although-web-browser-works-on-same-computer this might help you @MarkoZadravec

Comment: @SundeepPidugu, thanks for the link... I guess that is a router,.. but,.. he gets timeouts, I get host not found,.. is there a difference?

Comment: If it takes a longer time for response it will be timed-out else it will have not found if it is not able to access at all.